# c - iterating through field from txt file causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, field, fopen, fread

So I'm creating a program called convert.c that takes in data from a csv file and writes the data to a new textfile called data.bin (but with alterations to the original csv file). One field/column of the csv file in particular contains a column of integers, which were written to the data.bin file. In my analyzeInjuries.c file, I'm trying to write a program that reads in the data.bin file and calculates the total number of integers within that specific column (representing the total number of injuries caused by hurricanes).

I calculated the total number of injuries in my convert.c file and printed it in the terminal. It worked, however when I try to do the same in the analyzeInjuries file, it prints a value of 0. I'm not sure why this is happening as the getfield function and calculations worked fine in convert.c.

I believe there is something wrong with the line char *two = getfield(buf, 2); because when I attempt to print all values in field two, it causes a segmentation fault. Any help with this would be extremely appreciated. I'm really confused as to what went wrong in the analyzeInjuries.c file.

analyzeInjuries.c:

```
    int numDisast= 0;

    while (fgets (buf, lineCount, fd)) {
        char *second = getfield (buf, 2); //printing second field causes seg fault
        int field = POINTER2INT(second);
        numDisast = numDisast + field;


    }
    printf("%d\n", numDisast);
    return 0;
}
```

The image below is a screenshot of the data.bin file. The red line indicates the field I'm trying to find the sum of.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. [Edit] your question and post a minimal version of your `data.bin` file as text. A [mcve]  should include the data.

Comment: <O/T> but giving a text file a ".bin" extension goes against convention. .bin is used for binary data, which cannot be meaningfully displayed with a text editor. Chances are you won't be using `fgets` to read and string operations on data pulled from a binary file.

Comment: That was the name of the file that was given to me. I don't know why it's called .bin but it's basically a txt file.

Comment: ah ok .. tell your supplier to get it together!

Comment: you're cramming a lot of functionality into the last 2 lines of `getfield`.. might be helpful to split some of that up into separate lines, step through with a debugger, and see that each operation is behaving as you expect. Easy to make mistakes with buffer overruns with all your memory copying and moving.

Comment: "char *second = getfield (buf, 3); //printing third field causes seg fault" is unclear as code never prints the third field.

Comment: Sorry, I meant second in this example. I'm unable to print any field using atoi() without causing a seg fault it seems.

Comment: I don't think your `POINTER2INT` macro does what you think it does... it doesn't get the number represented by the text, just its address as a (possibly truncated) integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "printing third field causes seg fault" you mean trying to print `second` variable.

`getfield()` returns NULL if it doesn't find the field and because it uses `,` as a separator and your `data.bin` doesn't use `,`, then it will always return NULL. Then when you try to print it, it will crash.

Beside that you are not really summing values in the column. Your `POINTER2INT` macro does not convert a string to an integer. You probably want to use `atoi()` instead.

EDIT

First: you should check for NULL in you loop:

```c
char *second = getfield (buf, 3);
if (second) {
    printf("found field: %s\n", second);
    numDisast = numDisast + atoi(second);
}
else {
    printf("field not found\n");
}
```

Second: your `data.bin` looks like it might use tabs instead of `,` as the separator. You could change `","` to `"\t"` in your call to `strsep()` and see if it helps.

Comment: Hi! I'm not really sure what to replace the comma in the while loop with. I tried commenting that whole line out in getfield() and did printf("%d", atoi(second)); instead of POINTER2INT but it still seems to cause a seg fault.